# Classification documents based on topic frequency

Tags: text, text-mining, text-analysis

I need a way to clarify The dominant topics for the following data set , the following data set produced after pre-processing all docs ,
the following selected topics frequencies are follow :

```
                                         TOPICS 
id   Doc-name   total words     Politics    sport    food   animals  
1       doc1        1000          300         250     100     350
2       doc2        2000          1000        400     200     400
3       doc3        4000          500         300     2000    200
etc...
```

question are :
is there any classification method for this kind of data set ? 
if I consider doc1 is animals is this true ?
is there any way to calculate probability of each topic in that document to find doc dominant topic ? 
any suggestion please ?

Comment: How do you calculate the score under each topic in this data set?

Comment: I have calculated as follow :
suppose document x contain the following words in its sentences  { dog , monkey , birds , cat , spider , cat , donkey , monkey  } then the animals topics will become for this document x is 8 .. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method of classification is only good when the type of document should be determine in relation to a given topic. In no way this type of analysis can give an idea of the real context it blogs to.

What is the context of the sentence if I say "*The athlete is certainly faster than any cat, dog, cow or a sheep*"? Does it speak about animals?

The only conclusion you can make about the context of the sentence through this type of analysis is that "*The sentence has factors leading to describe sports and animals. The participation of those factors are 4 to 2*".

You can go on calculating the probability using standard methods. But the relevance of the numbers to the real context can be distant.

Comment: thanks for explanation , what is the way to calculate probability for this kind ?

Comment: The kind of probability you can calculate here is the chance a random word belong to a particular topic. Let's say you have 5 animal words and 3 political words in a document. So the probability of any word becoming an animal is 5 / (5+3). As I said, you can never get an accurate hint of the real context of the article in this method. 

But, again, on practical grounds, there is a change any random article containing 600 political words out of 100 being a real political article. Just that there is no guarantee. In this case you can consider a simple majority.

Comment: thanks  , can you calculate he probability for my first instance just to programming it ?

Comment: Can you elaborate more please.

Comment: for my table I would like to calculate the probability of the political , sport , food ,  animals  ? how to calculate the probability of each topics , then is there is a way can be more efficient to classify each document based on { frequent words or topics } thanks

Comment: Probability is the measure of the likelihood that an event will occur. Clearly tell me for which event you need to calculate the probability. 

Ex: Likelihood I will pass my exam next summer. 
Ex: Likelihood the dice will roll to be 6

Comment: for example in my data set I need to calculate  the probability of doc1 is political or sport or animal etc ...
L= p(300/1000) or what .. 
i'm thinking to use threshold here so how to calculate the likelihood probability for each words in Doc1 ?

Comment: Probability of Doc1 being political (within all the limitations I noted in my answer) is 300 / 1000. In fact it is the real probability of any random word being political one. A better way to describe Doc 1 is that it has the relevance order of animal->political->sports->food. Or this Doc1 can have the tags in the above order. Thats more practical.